# Can we write audio binary data directly to gstreamer pipeline?

Tags: gstreamer

I want to write binary data directly to gstreamer pipeline but I'm unable to do so.

I had tried the rawaudioparse plugin. I had written the binary data into the .raw file and tried this command to play this binary data.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=audio.raw ! rawaudioparse use-sink-caps=false \
     format=pcm pcm-format=s16le sample-rate=48000 num-channels=2 \
     audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink
```

My goal is to write audio binary data to gstreamer pipeline and play that as RTMP streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this using the element [`fdsrc`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-fdsrc.html), which takes a file descriptor (by default: standard input) from which it will start reading data.

Your GStreamer pipeline will then look like this:

```
# Replace "cat audio.raw" with your actual commands
cat audio.raw | gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc ! rawaudioparse (...)
```